# problem while using extern variable

Tags: c++

```
//FILE 1
char *ptr="Sample";

void SomeFunction() {
  cout<<ptr<<endl;
}

//FILE 2

void SomeFunction();
int main() 
{
  extern char ptr[];
  SomeFunction();
  cout<<ptr<<endl;
}
```

`ptr` in the main function is printing some garbage value. please let me know the reason.

Comment: what compiler are you using ? this program even doesn't compile with `g++`. `char *ptr = "<string literal>";` is depricated.

Comment: @iammilind: It certainly should compile in any conforming compiler (although perhaps with warnings); as you say, it's deprecated, not ill-formed.

Answer (score 3):

`ptr` is declared as a pointer in file 1, and as an array in file 2. Pointers and arrays are not the same thing, even if they behave similarly sometimes.

Make sure your `extern` declaration matches the type of the variable specified in its definition.

Comment: If they are different, i should get linking error in the file 2

Comment: @Ramesh: No, you won't get linker errors because the linker doesn't know the type of the symbols, just their names. What you should do is declare everything in header files, and include these from your source files, so that you'll get compiler errors if the types don't match.

Answer (score 3):

1. never declare local extern variables, all extern variables are by definition global, declaring them localy will cause confusion
2. use a matching type `extern char *ptr;`
3. string literals are `const char*` not `char *`

Comment: @madhavarao Hmm, and what did you expect? You have three errors in the code, you are experiencing the results of the number (2), but (1) and (3) are equally dangerous.

Comment: I am getting the expected  answer, if i use extern char *ptr. But when i am trying to use extern char ptr[], i am getting some garbage value to ptr in file 2. What do u think abt this error. please let me know...

Comment: @madhavarao Yes, as I wrote in my answer, you need to use a matching type. Your variable is `char *ptr`, therefore the extern has to be `extern char *`. It's that simple.

Comment: (1) the declaration will only confuse (some) humans, not the compiler; an `extern` declaration at block scope refers to an entity in the enclosing namespace, so in this case it does refer to `ptr` from file 1. (2) answers the question; (3) is good advice, but not the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `char*` versus `char[]` could have been caught if you had written a header file that corresponded with your file1.cpp.

```
// file1.h

extern char* ptr;        // Corresponds to your implementation

// Better:
extern const char * ptr; // Consistent with assignment to a string literal

// Alternative:
extern char ptr[];       // Would require changing implementation in file1 to
                         // char ptr[] = "Hello world";
```

Your file2.cpp is doing something very bad: It is declaring the `extern` pointer itself. Never do that. Instead, file2.cpp should `#include` this new header file, *as should file1.cpp*. This way you will find inconsistencies such as the one that you ran across.

Comment: Please don't say "implementation" when you are referring to 3 lines of code.

Comment: @ Ярослав: The standard uses "declaration" and "definition", two terms that are near-synonyms to me and to others. The term "implementation" fits when applied to a function. `void foo(int);` is the declaration of some function, `void foo (int num) { ... }` is its definition (or implementation). The same concept applies to variables that need to be defined (or implemented) at file scope.

Comment: I'm not going to defeat you on the definition. But saying "to implement a variable" is ridiculous, and even technically incorrect. Declaration of a var - yes, initialization - yes, implementation - hardly. To me, an IMPLEMENTATION (programming) is a substantial body of work: "impl. of the floating point numbers in sun jre 1.4", the "impl. of roller-coaster tycoon in assembly", etc. I can see how the term might prove useful when explaining polymorphism and how different implementations of "the same function" will run to cs students, but the term should have a certain gravity imho.

Comment: And you downvoted over a quibble over terminology? Please. `int foo()` declares the function foo. `int foo () {return 0;}` is a (trivial) implementation of the function. Too many people get confused with the term 'definition'. BTW, initialization is definitely the wrong term. Global variables need to have a place to live. There is a big difference between 'definition' (or 'implementation') and 'initialization'.

Comment: Yes because saying that someone is implementing a variable is at the very least confusing (makes me think of handling variables are handled in the compiler, of which I know nothing). Instead of confusing some one with "will require changing your implementation" and "corresponds to your implementation" you could have said "as you wrote in your source file" and "needs to be declared as an array".

Answer (score 0):

`char *` and `char []` are not the same thing.  One is a pointer, and the other is an array.  See [this page](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) from the C FAQ.

Either change your definition in File1, or change your declaration in File2.

Comment: it's compiling and i am getting some garbage value for ptr in the main function

Comment: if i change char *ptr to ptr[] i am getting cannot convert from 'const char [7]' to 'char [7]' error

Comment: Sure, its compiling. You have two compilation units that have inconsistent definitions of your `ptr`. Those two compilation units don't know about one another. Ensuring such consistency between compilation units is one of the many reasons why header files exist.

Answer (score 0):

Im trying not to forget everything I learnt a year ago, so here is how it should be:

Look at Let_Me_Be's answer for good comments.

Your main function is printing garbage because the variable you declare there is not the same as in the first file.

```
$ cat print.cpp  ;echo ---; cat print2.cpp 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
const char *ptr = "Hello";
void sayLol(){
        cout<<ptr<<endl;
}
---
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
void sayLol();
int main(void){
        extern char *ptr;
        sayLol();
        cout<<ptr<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It's k, if i sue "extern char *ptr". I am trying to know why i am getting some garbage value whan i am using "extern char ptr[]......

Comment: Its because char ptr[] points to cells [a][b][c][d][e] and ptr is the first. you could access them like for (int=0; i<; i; i++) { puts (\*(0+i));} .... or something like that. While ptr* points to [abcde] - its becasue of how you declared it. char *ptr = "Hello" is like saying make a string at address ptr, while the array declaration extern char ptr[]; is like saying there is a number of cells in some other file with the first cell in [] so when you use "ptr[]" later you get the address of cell 1 and that is the garbage you see - address in ram.